# Cannot get my app to appear in business page list

Tags: facebook-canvas

I have created a basic app/landing page for a client and I want to add it to the clients business page. I did the same thing a month ago and it worked fine but now I cannot figure out how to get the app I created to appear in the list on the left. this is the business account I am trying to add my app to

http://www.facebook.com/OceansM

and this is the app landing page

http://apps.facebook.com/oceans_mooloolaba

this is the page it did work on

can some one help I cannot figure it out and its driving me crazy is it do with the clients page i am adding it to?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the result of Facebook's new SSL host requirement for apps and iframes beginning Oct. 1.

To self host it seems that you need a domain with SSL certification, an add-on as cheap as $10, and a dedicated IP address from your host.

http://www.blogaid.net/facebook-iframes-and-ssl-certificates-explained

---

Sorry just say your app is hosted on a proper https page, don't know what your issue may be,  still it's probably an issue for others.

Comment: You can get a trusted SSL certificate for less than $10 - they're free from https://www.startssl.com/ for example

Comment: Yeh its hosted on BC using world secure systems I thought that would be fine to use as a secure location.